# TableView with all the Idioms

Tags: arrays, swift, tableview, idioms

I have a tableView and I would like to show to the user a list of the languages, and the user can select one or more spoken languages. Is there a way for swift to show a list of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your`TableViewControlloer`

```
let langues = ["Mandarin","Spanish","English","Hindi","Arabic","Portuguese","Bengali","Russian","Japanese","Punjabi"]
```

Override following two function

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = langues[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

and

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    if (cell?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark){

        cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None;

    }else{

        cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark;

    }
}
```

This will give you the option to select multiple row item as follows

[image: Multiple Row Selection in table view]

Comment: I think, I didn't explain well. I meant, how to make a table or array, that already contains all the languages, without typing one by one. I just thought maybe there is a function that does it.